# Draw Color Cubes / Planes with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to reproduce the following figure in TikZ.
But I can't get it to work :(
[image]
Is there maybe a package which can help and draw that easily.

Comment: What have you tried until now? It does not seem difficult with normal `tikz`, by changing the `opacity` value of the squares. Altough the generation of the MSI and HSI colors seems to be quite cubersome, even using a `foreach` loop or something similar.

Comment: Also, draw from the back to the front.

Comment: I edited my answer below to make some adjustments and add a shadow. Feel free to vote and accept if it fulfills your demand ;)

Answer (score 6):

Your version is almost achived, congratulations. I used some of your work and add a bit of mine.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\defclr}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\wavelen{\wavemax-(\wavemax-\wavemin)*\i/\t}
    \definecolor{clr}{wave}{\wavelen}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=Stealth,
        every node/.style={scale=1.5},
        x={(0.19 cm,0.16 cm)},
        y={(0 cm,1 cm)},
        z={(1 cm,0 cm)}
        ]
        
        \draw [->] (-1,0,0) -- (40,0,0) node [at end, above] {$\lambda$};
        \draw [->] (0,-1,0) -- (0,6,0) node [at end, left] {$y$};
        \draw [->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,20) node [at end, above] {$z$};
        
        \def\t{18} \def\op{0.6}
        \def\wavemax{420} \def\wavemin{650} % obvious, isn't it?
        \def\l{2.5} %length of the squares
        \def\a{1} \def\b{7} \def\c{13} % z pos of the square stacks
        
        \foreach \i in {0,9,...,\t}
            {
            \defclr
            \fill[clr,opacity=\op] (\t-\i+3,0,\a) rectangle ++ (0,\l,\l);
            }       
        
        \foreach \i in {0,3,...,\t}
            {
            \defclr
            \fill[clr,opacity=\op] (\t-\i+3,0,\b) rectangle ++ (0,\l,\l);
            }
        
        \foreach \i in {0,0.5,...,\t}
            {
            \defclr
            \fill[clr,opacity=\op] (\t-\i+3,0,\c) rectangle ++ (0,\l,\l);
            }   
        
        \node[below=15pt] at (3,0,\a+.5*\l) {RGB};
        \node[below=15pt] at (3,0,\b+.5*\l) {MSI};
        \node[below=15pt] at (3,0,\c+.5*\l) {HSI};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Wavelengths]

#### EDIT

I searched a way to add a nice texture to the squares, like in the original picture but couldn't find any (any advice accepted in comment). But I thought it should be a good idea to add some blur shadows to give this picture a bit of life. So here is a second version with some adjustments and the shadows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows.blur}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\defclr}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\wavelen{\waveback-(\waveback-\wavefront)*\i/\t}
    \definecolor{clr}{wave}{\wavelen}}

\tikzset{myshadow/.style={blur shadow={shadow blur steps=50,shadow blur extra rounding=3pt,shadow xshift=5pt,shadow yshift=-5pt, shadow blur radius=3pt,shadow opacity=10}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >={Stealth[width=8pt, length=10pt]},
        every node/.style={scale=2},
        x={(0.12 cm,0.11 cm)},
        y={(0 cm,1 cm)},
        z={(1 cm,0 cm)} 
        ]
        
        \draw [->] (-2,0,0) -- (48,0,0) node [at end, above] {$\lambda$};
        \draw [->] (0,-.5,0) -- (0,6,0) node [at end, left] {$y$};
        \draw [->] (0,0,-.5) -- (0,0,19) node [at end, above] {$x$};
        
        \def\t{18} \def\op{0.6}
        \def\waveback{440} \def\wavefront{650} % obvious, isn't it?
        \def\l{2.5} %length of the squares
        \def\a{1} \def\b{7} \def\c{13} % x pos of the square stacks
        
        \foreach \i in {0,9,...,\t}
            {
            \defclr
            \fill[myshadow,clr,opacity=\op] (\t-\i+3,0,\a) rectangle ++ (0,\l,\l);
            }       
        
        \foreach \i in {0,3,...,\t}
            {
            \defclr
            \fill[myshadow,clr,opacity=\op] (\t-\i+3,0,\b) rectangle ++ (0,\l,\l);
            }
        
        \foreach \i in {0,0.5,...,\t}
            {
            \defclr
            \fill[myshadow,shadow opacity=5,clr,opacity=\op] (\t-\i+3,0,\c) rectangle ++ (0,\l,\l);
            }   
            
        \def\dist{12pt}
        \node[below=\dist] at (3,0,\a+.5*\l) {RGB};
        \node[below=\dist] at (3,0,\b+.5*\l) {MSI};
        \node[below=\dist] at (3,0,\c+.5*\l) {HSI};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: V2]

Comment: Nice one ! at first look I thought it was Marmot.

Answer (score 5):

For the moment I ended up with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
 \def\total{15}
\newcommand{\plane}[3][fill=blue!10!white]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\wavelen{650-(650-420)*#2/\total}
    \definecolor{adc}{wave}{\wavelen}
   
    \fill[opacity=0.7,adc] (#3, 0, #2) rectangle (#3+3, 3, #2);
}
\hspace*{-4cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
% \begin{scope}[shift={(-15,0)}]
    %\coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,->] (O,0,16) --++ (16,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$z$};     
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,->] (O,0,16) --++ (0,8,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};     
    \draw[line width=0.4mm,->] (O,0,16) --++ (0,0,-25) node[anchor=east]{$\lambda$};
    
\node[below] at (2,0,17) {RGB};
\node[below] at (7,0,17) {Multispectral};
\node[below] at (12,0,17) {Hyperspectral};

    %\plane[draw=none,pattern=dots]{0};
     \def\total{15}
                
            %\foreach \x in {1,2,...,\total}
                %\plane{\x};
                
                \foreach \x in {1,7,...,\total}
                \plane{\x}{0};
                \foreach \x in {1,3,...,\total}
                \plane{\x}{5};
                \foreach \x in {1,1.5,...,\total}
                \plane{\x}{10};
%\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]